# EXC_BAD_ACCESS with getter

Tags: ios, objective-c, exc-bad-access

Having a problem with the following code (using xcode 5 with ios 7.1)

```
Player *aPlayer = theDungeon.thePlayer;
int r = aPlayer.lampRed;
int g = aPlayer.lampGreen;
int b = aPlayer.lampBlue;
```

```
Player *aPlayer = theDungeon.thePlayer;
```

returns a valid Player object which has each of the properties shows above and hovering over this variable and expanding it, I can see lampRed etc. just fine.

```
int r = aPlayer.lampRed;
```

At this line I get the bad access error.

This is the property:

```
  @property int lampRed;
```

Any idea why?

Comment: You should post the property, ivar or accessor declarations and implementations.

Comment: I would declare your property like: `@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger lampRed;`.

Comment: Changing the property declaration had no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EXC_BAD_ACCESS appears when an object is not initialized or an object is already released.

So I think that you are not initialized the object correctly and you are trying to access a property of him.

You have to instantiate the object:

```
Player *aPlayer = [[Player alloc]init];
```

then u can access to his property's

Use:

```
@property(nonatomic, assign) int lampRed;
```

instead

```
@property int lampRed;
```

On the other hand, and this is very important, you have to use the property in .m file:

```
@synthesize lampRed;
```

With this you obtain the getters and setters, otherwise not.

Comment: Your last statement is not correct. Since Xcode 4.4 (LLVM Compiler 4.0) the compiler automatically synthesizes getter, setter and instance variable. An explicit `@synthesize` statement is *not* necessary.

Comment: The object is allocated and, as stated in post, the variables lampred etc are visible when I expand in the debugger.  Changing the property declaration had no effect.